# Pulling docker image using Ubuntu

Tags: docker, caffe

I correctly install docker and test it. i pull some of images using

> docker pull imagename

but i am having problem while pulling caffe image.

i used the command

> 'docker pull bvlc/caffe'

and i get the following error:

> Error response from daemon: manifest for bvlc/caffe:latest not found

Please note that docker pull Ubuntu is working and Ubuntu image is on my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this command:

```
docker pull bvlc/caffe:cpu
```

Refer to [this official readme link](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/master/docker)

Hop this help!